# Probability of tie

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy

[image] what is the probability of tie and how to calculate it?  How to determjne winning percentage

Comment: That is 2 questions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the situation is that both players are all in on the trun.

1. A tie will happen if the river is a Q(2 outs) or a 6(3 outs) = 5 outs
2. KQ will win if river is a K (3 outs)
3. Remaining cards is deck = 44

So the % are

```
% win KQ = 3/44 * 100 = 6.8%
% tie = 5/44 * 100 = 11.4%
% win AQ = 100 - 6.8 - 11.4 = 81.8%
```